# How to edit a webpage to show locally

Tags: html, mocking

So for a school project my sister has to make a "Historical Instagram," essentially its instagram mock post with a post from Washington and Benjamin Franklin liking the photo and commenting on it.

What I want to do it locally edit an instagram post using inspect and then screen cap it.

I know how to change the text on the comments using inspect tool, that's the easy part. What I need help with is the profile images.

I have the pictures I need in the correct pixel sizes with the correct picture types as far as I can tell. I just can't figure out for the life of me how to change it. When I tried to change the src="" I just get the default icon of a broken image. The one with a green mountain that is split in half.
I am new to programing and scripting in general and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

---

If you change the src="" you have to put into an internet link not a local image !

And for the other thing you can do :

```
  border: 2px double gray;
  border-radius: 100px;
```

to make it in a circle :p

Enjoy coding !

Comment: is there a way to use a local image?

Comment: I don't think so, you can search on google but i am not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use local resources when the web  page is running on the web server

If you want use local resource in web page at first you have to save that web page locally. you can save it by pressing ctr+s then you can add local resource files by mentioning its path (eg file:///C:/Users/foldername/filename.extension).

In the local file you can add js,css anything whatever you want you can add it and test it.